# Create a BLOB/CLOB to save excel files into DB2

Tags: db2, blob, clob

I would like to know how can I save several excel files into DB2 using a blob/clob object. Can anyone try to explain me how to reach the goal or redirect me to some documentation or similar issues?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: regarding this issue, none yet

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @data_henrik ;) very usefull!

Answer (score 0):

db2 IMPORT utility can do this.

Look at the [LOB import considerations](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/c0004581.html).
If you table `newtable` has `(i int, b blob(1m))` columns, you can prepare a text file `inputfile.del` with the following contents.

```
1,"file1.xls"
2,"file2.xls"
```

and import the data with the following command (it expects your `xls` files in the `/tmp/data` dir, and `inputfile.del` in the current directory):

```
IMPORT FROM inputfile.del OF DEL 
    LOBS FROM /tmp/data 
    MODIFIED BY lobsinfile
    INSERT INTO newtable
```